# htmlwidgets: TypeError: results is undefined

Tags: r, d3.js, shiny, typeerror

I've tweaked D3's bullet chart [(link)](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961) and added it to R using the `htmlwidgets` package. You can view the source of my package [here](https://github.com/tejas-kale/d3baseline).

When rendered in the R console, the chart is seen as expected but when I try the same in a Shiny app, nothing is to be seen. When I check the console in Firefox, I see the error `TypeError: results is undefined`. Here is the code for Shiny app

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
library(d3baseline)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    fluidPage(d3baselineOutput('chart'))

))


# server.R
library(shiny)
library(d3baseline)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$chart <- renderD3baseline(d3baseline(resources, x_label="Metric"))

})
```

The `d3baseline` package can be installed as follows:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("tejas-kale/d3baseline")
```

Pardon me if I'm being dense here but despite some attempts, I'm unable to determine what exactly is causing this error.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't reproduce your example but I detect some parts of your code that could be a problem: 1. `fliudPage` inside `fluidPage`. 2. functions `render` are used with `({...})` for arguments. Go to [shiny articles](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/) to see more

Comment: Thanks, Andriy. I rectified both the problem areas you highlighted and still no luck. How can I help you with reproducing my example?

Comment: Showing your table with `dput(resources)` or create a dummy data; and a function u use (can't find `d3baseline` package)

Comment: Andriy, I've edited the original post to show how to install d3baseline. Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I ran in something like this once, too. Try 
`htmlOutput` instead of `d3baselineOutput`. I think the htmlWidgets need the htmlOutput specified for output (So it is for rCharts and Gvis).

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Using `htmloutput` gives the error `TyperError: a is undefined`

Comment: Hm! I couldn't found the d3baseLine package anywhere. Can you reproduce the data, or provide more information about the data/package?

Comment: Robert, I've edited the original post to show how to install `d3baseline`. Any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Turned out to be a dependency error. I was loading JQuery in the .yaml file, but it was apparently already loaded.

For anyone who wanders across this in the future, try deactivating your dependencies one at a time to find the culprit. Once found, you can find a way to work around it.

Since I JQuery was already loaded, I just had to remove the JQuery path in my .yaml file.